# Android WebView unresponsive after pressing Enter using last visible input

Tags: android, html, webview, pixi.js

I have simple Android app which is just a WebView running a web application.

If I am using inputs and press enter on the last visible input, the keyboard goes away (which is fine), but I lose all ability to interact with the web application running in the WebView. I can still see the app functioning. Pressing back key instead of enter causes keyboard to go away and I have no problem.

Any idea whats happening and how I can get this to stop?

I have tried intercepting focus changes and requesting focus on the web view, but it seems the web view itself is never losing focus. I've also tried setting an interval to refocus the web apps document.body but it had no effect.

**Code:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context="com.particlesandbox.Play">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.view);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

}


<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Logcat:**

```
07-11 23:07:39.739 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/ViewRootImpl@db61f74[Play]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
07-11 23:07:39.742 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/framework/QPerformance.jar
07-11 23:07:39.752 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
07-11 23:07:39.752 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = null
07-11 23:07:39.805 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/ViewRootImpl@db61f74[Play]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
07-11 23:07:39.908 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/InputMethodManager: HSI from window - flag : 0 Pid : 17899
07-11 23:07:40.884 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/ViewRootImpl@db61f74[Play]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
07-11 23:07:43.086 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/ViewRootImpl@db61f74[Play]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
07-11 23:07:45.034 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/ViewRootImpl@db61f74[Play]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
07-11 23:07:45.105 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/ViewRootImpl@db61f74[Play]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
07-11 23:07:45.240 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@ab7d50f nm : com.particlesandbox ic=null
07-11 23:07:45.240 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
07-11 23:07:45.245 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=172
07-11 23:07:45.249 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=139
07-11 23:07:45.250 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/InputMethodManager: ISS - flag : 0Pid : 17899 view : com.particlesandbox
07-11 23:07:45.347 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=171
07-11 23:07:45.347 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/ViewRootImpl@eb7fa5[PopupWindow:bca799c]: setView = android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{3c7cf7a V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} touchMode=true
07-11 23:07:45.413 17899-18132/com.particlesandbox D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [60x72]-format:1
07-11 23:07:45.429 17899-19297/com.particlesandbox V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@2d39388 nm : com.particlesandbox ic=org.chromium.content.browser.input.ThreadedInputConnection@e397121
07-11 23:07:45.429 17899-19297/com.particlesandbox I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
07-11 23:07:45.457 17899-19297/com.particlesandbox D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=175
07-11 23:07:45.486 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/ViewRootImpl@eb7fa5[PopupWindow:bca799c]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
07-11 23:07:45.493 17899-19297/com.particlesandbox D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=172
07-11 23:07:45.870 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/ViewRootImpl@db61f74[Play]: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 750) or=1
07-11 23:07:48.698 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/ViewRootImpl@eb7fa5[PopupWindow:bca799c]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
07-11 23:07:48.738 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=171
07-11 23:07:48.772 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/InputMethodManager: HSI from window - flag : 0 Pid : 17899
07-11 23:07:48.820 17899-19297/com.particlesandbox V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@9ecd3d2 nm : com.particlesandbox ic=null
07-11 23:07:48.820 17899-19297/com.particlesandbox I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
07-11 23:07:48.825 17899-19297/com.particlesandbox D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=171
07-11 23:07:48.826 17899-19297/com.particlesandbox D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=175
07-11 23:07:48.854 17899-19297/com.particlesandbox W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
07-11 23:07:48.861 17899-19297/com.particlesandbox W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
07-11 23:07:48.951 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/ViewRootImpl@db61f74[Play]: MSG_RESIZED: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
07-11 23:07:50.895 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/ViewRootImpl@db61f74[Play]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
07-11 23:07:51.090 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/ViewRootImpl@db61f74[Play]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
07-11 23:07:51.132 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/InputMethodManager: HSI from window - flag : 0 Pid : 17899
07-11 23:07:51.482 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/ViewRootImpl@db61f74[Play]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
07-11 23:07:51.724 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/ViewRootImpl@db61f74[Play]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
07-11 23:07:51.783 17899-17899/com.particlesandbox D/InputMethodManager: HSI from window - flag : 0 Pid : 17899
```

Comment: I've changed my html to a simple page with one `<input />` and it doesn't have the problem.

Comment: I've isolated this to pixi.js causing a `<div style="width: 600px; height: 960px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 2;"></div>` to be created in front of my app when I tab off of the last input. It is reproducible in Chrome using the dev-tools device view.

Comment: Looks like it is the `AccessibilityManager`.

Answer (score 0):

It was the `AccessibilityManager` in Pixi.js.

As commented, it was creating a `div` in front of everything.

I destroyed it on my `renderer` and the problem went away.

`renderer.plugins.accessibility.destroy()`